# looping, timer and threading in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

how to I checking this script will be running every 2 minutes, where file 'odata_peng5.txt' still renewable every 2 minutes?

```
import pandas as pd
import threading

def printit():
      threading.Timer(120.0, printit).start()
      df = pd.read_csv('data_peng5.txt', header=None)

      a=100
      b=1/a

      df[15] = df[3]+b+50

      df.to_csv('odata_peng5.txt', header=None, index=False)

      print "Hello, World!"
printit()
```

Output:

```
=============== RESTART: C:/Users/xxx/timer3.py ===============
>>>
```

Even though, I'am testing with mode print mode still running:

```
#import pandas as pd
import threading

def printit():
  threading.Timer(120.0, printit).start()
  print "Hello, World!"

printit()
```

Output:

```
=============== RESTART: C:/Users/xxx/timer3.py ===============
Hello, World!
>>> Hello, World!
Hello, World!
```

Comment: share data_peng5.txt dummy format data

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading
def printit():
   threading.Timer(120.0, printit).start()
   print "Hello, World!"
t = threading.Timer(120.0, printit)
t.start()
```

this will repeat the printit function every 120s

Comment: thank for you answer sir @afsal, but i need output "odata_peng5.txt" sir, not  print "Hello, World!" , maybe you have recomended?

Comment: f = open('odata_peng5.txt','r')
    message = f.read()
    print message
    f.close() @ReduBen add these line to print the contents

Comment: according to your suggestion sir @afdal, i input that on my code, but appear some error >>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bondan\zz BlajarPy\timer3.py", line 22, in <module>
    printit()
  File "C:\Users\Bondan\zz BlajarPy\timer3.py", line 17, in printit
    print massage
NameError: global name 'massage' is not defined

Comment: it is Sir @afsal : http://www.mediafire.com/file/d0r1z8t81k415uz/Sir_Afdal.rar/file

Comment: @ReduBen I couldn't open that link

Answer (score 0):

newer code

```
import pandas as pd
import threading

def printit():
      threading.Timer(60.0, printit).start()
      df = pd.read_csv('data_peng5.txt', header=None)

      a=100
      b=1/a

      df[15] = df[3]+b+50

      df.to_csv('odata_peng5.txt', header=None, index=False)

      #YourCode Sir
      f=open('odata_peng5.txt','r')
      message = f.read()
      print massage
      f.close()

      print "Hello, World!"

printit()
```

Comment: it is Sir @Afsal Salim